# Can I splice a Cat6A patch cable in a Cat6 panel?

Tags: cat6

I have an existing Cat6 panel with Cat6 600MHz UTP cable spliced into it. I'd like to know if I can splice Cat6A cable into the same panel? Or would I have to buy a separate Cat6A panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CAT6 the conductors might be a different wire gauge than found in CAT6a, so you might not be able to properly terminate your connections. Your patch panel should display which AWG size range it supports. and your cabling should also display that.  But you could always simply try with one and measure the resulting connection...